# UITabBar does not have the correct position after the CallKit call

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I use `CallKit` for calls within the test application. When I end the call, sometimes I get the wrong position of some UI elements, for example `UITabBar` and `UITableView`. When I was able to catch this behavior of the elements, I used the **Xcode View UI Hierarchy**, and looked that in normal state `UITabBar` has Y equal to 618 on iPhone 4.7 (in this case I have iPhone 7), and in case where the wrong behavior is obtained, `UITabBar` has Y is equal to 638 (a difference of 20 points). How can I fix it? Thanks.

I add screenshots to illustrate the incorrect UI.

This is how the UI looks after CallKit is terminated.
[image]
This is how UI looks in the View UI Hierarchy

[image]

This is the UITabBar value in the correct state

[image]

This is the UITabBar value in the incorrect state

[image]

Comment: can you please provide the code for dismiss button action?

Comment: @shivi_shub I can't, I'm not working on this project anymore.